# RXJS - Angular - unsubscribe from Subjects

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subject

As described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription), 'official' solution to unsubscribe from Observables in Angular 5+ in general is using takeUntil. So far, so good. My question is, does this also apply if the Observable I am subscribed to is actually a Subject?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter because `Subject` extends `Observable` class. This applies to `EventEmitter` as well because it extends `Subject` class.

Comment: as martin said, yes. Basically anytime you subscribe to something, you should destroy that subscription (unsubscribe) at some point in time, to avoid memory leaks, no matter what  you are subscribing to.

Comment: To add to above, OnDestroy is a great thing to implement for destroying subscriptions in components. http://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/

Comment: Also, put takeUntil as last operator to avoid messing up the unsubscribe: https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-avoiding-takeuntil-leaks-fb5182d047ef

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Once you call `.subscribe()` on anything (subjects too), something needs to make sure the subscription gets unsubscribed.

**Dealing with the finite Observables**:
If you subscribe to a finite observable (meaning an observable that has a finite/limited sequence), the last message will send an end signal and the subscription will be canceled automatically.
Examples of this are:

```
Observable.of(100)
Observable.from([1,2,3,4])
```

Examples of **in**finite observables are:

```
Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click')
Observable.timer(1000)
```

Calling/piping `.first()`, `.take(number)` or `.takeWhile(condition that will evaluate to false at some point)` or `takeUntil(observable that emits a value)` on an observable will all turn an otherwise infinite observable into a finite one.

**Stop calling .subscribe()**:
Another popular method of not having to unsubscribe is by not subscribing in the first place. This might sound stupid, since when would you want an observable that you do not subscribe to? Well if you only need to pass some data to your view/HTML template, piping that observable into the async pipe will pass the unsubscribing issue to the async pipe itself.

Typical examples in the HTML template:

```
<h1>Editing {{ infiniteObservable$ | async }}<h1>
<li *ngFor="let user of userObservable$ | async as users; index as i; first as isFirst">
   {{i}}/{{users.length}}. {{user}} <span *ngIf="isFirst">default</span>
</li>
```

**Manually unsubscribing**: Lastly, you can choose to keep references to all subscriptions. You don't have to keep a variable pointing to each subscription, it's easier to just use a single Subscription object to keep track of all the subscriptions, and then unsubscribe to all of them at once.
Here is an example:

```
const subscriptions = new Subscription();
subscriptions.add(observable1$.subscribe());
subscriptions.add(observable2$.subscribe());
subscriptions.unsubscribe();
```

**Quick summarize**, how to handle unsubscriptions, any of the below methods:

1. Turn infinite observables into finite ones, hereby removing the need to unsubscribe (use `.takeUntil(this.destroyed$)` and do `this.destroyed$.next()` in `ngOnDestroy()`).
2. Avoid subscribing, and passing the observable through the `async` pipe.
3. Keep a reference to any subscriptions and call `.unsubscribe()` in the `ngOnDestroy()` method.

Personally I tend to only use one of the two first methods.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Why would you use takeWhile() instead of takeUntil(), as read in the thread I pointed to? xxx

Comment: Oh it shouldn't matter, I guess takeUntil would be more standard as the boolean variable would start by being false (default) and flipped to true instead of the other way around.

Comment: @didgewind Both operators transform an infinite into a finite observable, which means you don't need unsubscribe. Pick the one you feel is easier to read (when you or someone else needs to maintain your code later)

Comment: @PerHornshøj-Schierbeck what if you want to `unsubscribe` from `activatedRoute` `queryParams` in `app.component.ts` just after one `subscription`?

Comment: so http call is a finite observable or ?

Comment: @kuldeep yes i think all the calls are (but atleast the common ones, like get/post), because it only triggers once and angular handles unsubscription afterwards

Answer (score 2):

I have something to add. `Subject` stores the subscribers internally (`Observable` does too). If the `Subject` is part of your component (created inside, stored as property or in a closure) the subject and it's subscriptions are garbage collected with the component itself.

But this is a special case and one should be very careful with it: everything must be contained in the component.

It is e.g. safe to **not** unsubscribe from a `FormControl.valueChanges` observable if it is used in the component only.

But to be on the safe side, and don't want to think about it, just use `takeUntil`.

Comment: Can you please point me to some documentation that shows the cleanup of Angular components including unsubscribing from Subjects?

Comment: Is there really no need to explicitly call mySubject.unsubscribe on a component's onDestroy?