# Modyfing data in an observable

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following observable: `messages$: Observable<Message[] | undefined>`. `Message` has 2 fields: `id` and `content`, both of which are string.

What I would like to do is to modify `messages$` so that a function `foo(string)` is invoked on the `content` of each `Message`.

It doesn't seem difficult at face value but I'm new to observables and unfortunately I got stuck.

Comment: please add your code, so we know what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

I guess solution is simple:

```
messages$: Observable<Message[] | undefined> = yourSource
  .pipe(
    map(messages => {
      messages.forEach(value => {
        value.content = foo(value.content);
      });
      return messages;
    }
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is how can you change your Observable to an observable with sideeffect. You probably don't ever want that (except for simple cases like logging stuff).

Instead what you want to do is subscribe to that Observable and then do your logic in the subscription. That way you're also guaranteed that your logic is only run once (or the number you want) instead of being reliant on something else subscribing to the observable.

```
messages$.subscribe(({ content }) => { foo(content); });
```

Be careful of subscription that is not unsubscribed.
Check out this question for a solution to that generic problem:
[RXJS - Angular - unsubscribe from Subjects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50629357/rxjs-angular-unsubscribe-from-subjects)

If i misunderstood your question, and what you really want is an observable that transforms the data, and your `foo` method is pure (does not modify the inputs or other external data), the solution is different:

```
const modifiedMessages$ = messages$.pipe(map(({ content }) => foo(content));
```